# Автолайк при принятии ответа

Tags: предложение, принятые-ответы, голоса-за

В общем, иногда на ответ ставится галка, но в свою очередь ТС не ставит лайк на него.

Разве может быть какая-то мотивация не ставить лайк ответу, который принимаешь кроме того, как забыть это сделать?

Почему бы не ввести автолайк при принятии ответа?

Comment: за 5 (кажется) принятых ответов с нулевым рейтингом даже бэджик дают. Вы хотите лишить людей такого бэджика? 

Comment: @Эникейщик ввести открытие данного значка за донат. Покупаешь лут-боксы и имеешь шанс получить этот значок. Проекту лишние деньги не помешают=DD

Comment: ну это то же самое, что спортивные медали за деньги продавать!

Answer (score 10):

1. У спрашивающего может быть недостаточно репутации, чтобы поставить плюс. 
   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up
2. Спрашивающий мог извести весь дневной лимит голосов.
   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/suffrage
   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi
3. Некоторые при равнозначных ответах одному ставят плюс, а другой принимают.
4. У него могут быть какие-то свои причины :)

Comment: Можно, например, сделать, что бы принятие ответа не расходовало суточный лимит лайков. Я, обычно, лайками вознаграждаю остальные ответы, которые не принял, но ответы очень качественно оформлены и дополняют принятый ответ.

Comment: @iluxa1810, я тоже. Но не все так делают. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: А ещё можно поставить галочку и минуснуть. Вот это самый сок. Например, на метах, когда ответ не нравится, но понимаешь, что он лучше всего отражает реальное состояние дел.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ предлагаю сделать автодизлайк для меты.